# Store values that are only numerical or alphabetical in Pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Imagine I have a column called `courses`, where some are only numeric, some are alphabetical, some are both. These correspond to courses within a specific department. Imagine all values in `courses` are strings and there could be null values. I want to a) store the courses the are only numeric b) store the courses that are only alphabetical or c) store the courses that end with a number (but we don't care whether they otherwise contain numbers or letters). How could I do this leveraging Pandas capabilties?

Imagine `courses` looks something like this but much longer.

```
Courses
------------------------
181
71
CS 143
Machine Learning
Programming Languages 79
115
157 Neural Networks
```

So a) would contain 181, 71, 115 b) would contain Machine Learning and c) would contain Programming Languages 79, CS 143.

I could imagine doing this the longer way using non pandas approaches, but I imagine pandas can help significantly with this. For example, for the last task, I could do something along the lines of the following but am wondering if there is nicer way:

```
c = []
for course in courses:
    course = course.strip()
    if course:
        length = len(course) - 1
        if (course[length]).isdigit():
            c.append(course)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask:

```
m1 = df['Courses'].str.contains('^\d+$')
m2 = df['Courses'].str.contains('\d')
m3 = df['Courses'].str.contains('^\D.*\d$')

df1 = df[m1]
print (df1)
  Courses
0     181
1      71
5     115

df2 = df[~m2]
print (df2)
            Courses
3  Machine Learning

df3 = df[m3]
print (df3)
                    Courses
2                    CS 143
4  Programming Languages 79
```

---

If you need a single dataframe as the output, you can use a single regex:

```
df[df.Courses.str.contains(r'^(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z\s]+|.*\d)$')]

                    Courses
0                       181
1                        71
2                    CS 143
3          Machine Learning
4  Programming Languages 79
5                       115
```